# Fastboot on Samsung devices

Tags: samsung, fastboot

I was trying to do some fastboot commands on my Galaxy devices (Galaxy S4, 9515, 4Tab4), I start with fastboot devices and I am getting nothing (after `adb reboot bootloader`), is there any problem with samsung devices?

Answer (score 13):

Simple... Samsung devices do not support fastboot, you use Odin or Heimdall to flash what you need.

Comment: I did try Odin to flash my Samsung device with the TWPR , and Odin crash after like 15 minutes, is there any thing we should do after using Odin ?

Comment: @medlamineSemassel ODIN is a software that runs on your PC not on your phone, once it flashes TWRP (should only take a few seconds), you don't need it anymore. Perhaps I am not understanding your problem, but this maybe a different issue than your original question. Be aware there are lots of tutorials and information on the internet regarding this device, it is very common. A good place to start would be here: http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s4

Answer (score 1):

Finally It works for me this way :

1. Got the CF-Auto-Root-xxxx-xxxxx-gti9515.zip from : https://autoroot.chainfire.eu/
2. unzip CF-Auto-Root-xxxx-xxxxx-gti9515.zip
3. mv CF-Auto-Root-xxxx-xxxxx-gti9515.tar.md5 CF-Auto-Root-xxxx-xxxxx-gti9515.tar
4. tar xvf CF-Auto-Root-xxxx-xxxxx-gti9515.tar
5. Put the device on Download mode ( Vol Down + Home + Power then Vol Up)
6. sudo heimdall flash --RECOVERY recovery.img --CACHE cache.img.ext4
7. after testing you have root rights ( adb shell & su )
8. sudo heimdall flash --RECOVERY recovery.img ( TWRP )

Then you can go to recovery mode and use TWRP to install custom ROMs.

Comment: Thank you! Additionally - some devices like mine do not work well with Heimdall 1.4.1 and need latest 1.4.2 to work. I had to go according https://github.com/Benjamin-Dobell/Heimdall/issues/292 and compile it manually by https://github.com/Benjamin-Dobell/Heimdall/wiki/Build-instructions-(Linux)