# ADB detects my device but fastboot doesn't

Tags: fastboot

i am wanting to unlock the bootloader on my Samsung Galaxy A5 2017. The problem that I have encountered is that fastboot doesn't actually detect my device but adb does!

I have tried 'adb devices' and that finds my device but when i try 'fastboot devices' it doesn't appear with anything.

If you have any solutions please tell me!

Comment: Please make yourself familiar with the basics about the two first (our [fastboot tag-wiki](/tags/fastboot/info) would already answer your question). It's totally normal that when ADB is able to detect your device fastboot is not – and vice versa.

Comment: I have already read that and none of the solutions work.

Comment: So you have booted into fastboot mode, and there `fastboot devices` did not detect your device? What OS you're on? In case of Windows, the correct drivers are installed? Note that many devices present a different device ID when in fastboot mode.

Comment: Yes, when i boot into fastboot mode and run the command 'fastboot devices' no info appears. I don't know what drivers exactly if its like usb drivers or something but all i can find on the internet is usb drivers. Also im on windows so...

Comment: I have found the problem, the computer itself doesn't detect my phone when its in fastboot mode. idk why but i will do some research.

Comment: When you figured it out, be welcome to [answer your own question](/help/self-answer) – might help others in similar situations :) Good luck, and fingers crossed!

Comment: After a lot of research, i still can't find a solution :( Any ideas? Im not sure if it's usb drivers because i downloaded drivers from smart switch. Plus my phone is detected when charging and turned off completely. Has Samsung possibly put in some kind of security feature like knox? idk i will keep trying

Comment: Good look, but somebody else must pick up here – I'm double-out (no Windows, no Samsung here).

Comment: According to someone on xda fastboot isn't supported on Samsung and i just need to enable oem unlock in settings :/

Comment: That someone might be right, I vaguely remember heaving heard the same: on Samsung devices, there instead is "Download mode" to communicate with [Odin](/tags/odin/info)/[Heimdall](/tags/heimdall/info).

Comment: @Izzy:  You are correct.  [This answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/162664/fastboot-on-samsung-devices#162667) confirms it.

Comment: Well i didn't know that answer was a thing...

Comment: @Slinver I take that as confirmation (and mark this as duplicate). If I was wrong, let me know.